# Revert Rails 5 API-Only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-5

I created a Rails 5 App API-Only to be used by my iOS application.

But now I need a Back Office for the admins to approve, write messages to users, etc...

Do we have a way to revert the API-Only and have a normal Rails app ? (have views, etc...)

Comment: Could you continue with the API and have the an UI developed in React or [vue.js](https://vuejs.org) to do the job? The created 'views' will consume the APIs

Comment: The `--api` parameter is not something that big. As said http://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html#the-basic-configuration it's only some middleware not present and I think you can easily make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the admin functionality is all that you want to add, then you can just extend your app with one of the Admin frameworks([Compatibility Chart](http://www.carlosramireziii.com/rails-5-api-mode-admin-framework-compatibility-chart.html)):

- Active Admin
- Rails Admin
- Administrate